# Django urlresolvers: Need more than 2 values to unpack

Tags: django

I'm trying to upgrade from Django 1.3 to Django 1.4. I'm stuck with this error:

> Python Version:        2.7.3
>   Django Version:    1.4.10
>   Exception Type:    ValueError
>   Exception Value:   **need more than 2 values to unpack**

The line that triggers that error is (In template /var/www/proj/src_1.4/templates/fragments/header.html, error at line 20):

```
    <a id="login" href="{% url login %}" rel="nofollow">{% trans "Login" %}</a>
```

It works fine in Django 1.3.

I've tried the following:

```
python manage.py shell
>> from django.conf.urls import *
>> from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
>> reverse('login')
```

Then this error appears:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/www/proj/env_1.4/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/shell.pyc in <module>()
----> 1 reverse('login')

/var/www/proj/env_1.4/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.pyc in reverse(viewname, urlconf, args, kwargs, prefix, current_app)
474             resolver = get_ns_resolver(ns_pattern, resolver)
475 
--> 476     return iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs))
477 
478 reverse_lazy = lazy(reverse, str)

/var/www/proj/env_1.4/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.pyc in _reverse_with_prefix(self, lookup_view, _prefix, *args, **kwargs)
363         possibilities = self.reverse_dict.getlist(lookup_view)
364         prefix_norm, prefix_args = normalize(_prefix)[0]
--> 365         for possibility, pattern, defaults in possibilities:
366             for result, params in possibility:
367                 if args:

ValueError: need more than 2 values to unpack
```

If I look at the info showed by Django when I try to load my project, "Local vars" shows that info:

```
self    <RegexURLResolver urls (None:None) ^/>
args    ()
_prefix u'/'
possibilities   [([(u'accounts/login/', [])], 'accounts/login/$')]
lookup_view u'login'
prefix_norm u'/'
prefix_args []
kwargs  {}
```

Code in proj/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import *

urlpatterns += patterns('',
    url(r'^', include('home.urls')),                
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^accounts', include('accounts.urls')),
```

Code in apps/accounts/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

urlpatterns = patterns('',
url(r'^/register$',
    'accounts.views.register',
    name='register'),
url(r'^/login/$',
    'django.contrib.auth.views.login',
    {'template_name': 'accounts/login.html', 'authentication_form': AuthenticationForm},
    name='login'),
```

I'll appreciate any help about that. Thanks.

Finally I found the error. It was an old app used for internationalization of URLs (i18nurls). Django 1.3 uses an external app, in Django > 1.4 internationalization was included in the core ([Django: Internationalization: in URL patterns](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/#internationalization-in-url-patterns)).

Thanks.

Comment: You get that error when python expects more values to display, like if you have a print statement: print("%s %s %s" % (var1, var2)). Python is expecting 3 values to unpack, but only two were given

Comment: Thanks for the info @aldux. I know that, but I don't know why django is not working properly.

Comment: Since a simple `reverse('login')` manages to trigger the problem, its cause is very apparently _not_ within any of the code you have posted so far. Please post your `urls.py` module(s).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this will fix your errors, but try to do the following:
In your main **url.py** replace

```
url(r'^accounts', include('accounts.urls')),
```

with

```
url(r'^accounts/', include('accounts.urls')), ### add the slash /
```

It is better to include the `slash /` in the outer urlpatterns rather then in the inner one.

Then, in the **urls.py** inside `accounts` replace

```
url(r'^/register$',...
url(r'^/login/$',....
```

with

```
url(r'^register/$',...   ### delete dhe leading slashed, because you added it in `accounts/`
url(r'^login/$',....     ### finish both regex with the slash
```

Another suggestion would be to add a namespace:

```
url(r'^accounts/', include('accounts.urls', namespace='accounts')),
```

Now refer inside to your template with `"{% url 'accounts:login' %}"`

In this way you will know better which url comes from which app. Check if these tips fixed your bug and if no, let me know

Comment: Thanks for the info. I made the changes in the code, and still raising the same error. I've tried to debug in django 1.3 and 1.4, and the problem is with line 365 `for possibility, pattern, defaults in possibilities:`. The value of possibilities is: `[([(u'accounts/login/', [])], u'accounts/login/$')]`, both in django 1.3 and 1.4. In django 1.3 there is no problem because for loop only expect 2 values: `for possibility, pattern in possibilities:`. The problem is `defaults` variable. What value expects `defaults`?

Comment: Thanks @Mihai, finally I've found the problem, it was an old Internationalization app that is using in Django 1.3.

Answer (score 0):

If this is your full urls.py code

from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
url(r'^/register$',
    'accounts.views.register',
    name='register'),
url(r'^/login/$',
    'django.contrib.auth.views.login',
    {'template_name': 'accounts/login.html', 'authentication_form': AuthenticationForm},
    name='login'),
```

check you have not added the closing bracket )

from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
url(r'^/register$',
    'accounts.views.register',
    name='register'),
url(r'^/login/$',
    'django.contrib.auth.views.login',
    {'template_name': 'accounts/login.html', 'authentication_form': AuthenticationForm},
    name='login'),
)
```